# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in dart/ flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, api, dart

I can decode response from server but i don't know what is this error for :\

here's my request code in showproduct class:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      setState(() {
        var bodybytedecoded= jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

  final product= ProductModel.fromJson(bodybytedecoded); // console shows error come from this line
        print(product);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
```

In my Model class i have :

```
class ProductModel{
   final  int id;
   final  String name;
   final String regular_price;
   final String description;
   final List<ImageModel> image;

  ProductModel({ required this.id,required this.name,required this.regular_price,  required this.description,required this.image});

  factory ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json){
    final name = json["name"];
    final id = json ["id"];
    final regular_price = json["regular_price"];
    final description = json["description"];
    final image = json["image"];
    return ProductModel(id: id, name: name, regular_price: regular_price, description: description, image: image);
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data["id"] = this.id;
    data["name"] = this.name;
    data["regular_rice"] = this.regular_price;
    data["description"] = this.description;
    data["image"] = this.image;
    return data;
  }
}

class ImageModel{
   final String src;
  ImageModel({required this.src});
  factory ImageModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json ){
    return ImageModel(src:  json["src"]);
  }


}
```

i don't know what is this error for, is there any wrong with my model class? or my request?
i will be grateful if someone could show me a true way.

here's full error:

```
E/flutter (31338): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
E/flutter (31338): #0      _ShowProductState.FetchItems.<anonymous closure> (package:mystore/ProductPages/showproduct.dart:219:46)
E/flutter (31338): #1      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1088:30)
E/flutter (31338): #2      _ShowProductState.FetchItems (package:mystore/ProductPages/showproduct.dart:215:7)
E/flutter (31338): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (31338):
```

and here's the json body from server:

```
[
    {
        "id": 56012,
        "name": "a name",
        "slug": "a slug",
        "description": "<p>آب آشامیدنی پیورلایف 1/5 لیتری نستله</p>\n",
        "regular_price": "45000",
        "sale_price": "45000",
        "tags": [],
        "images": [
            {
                "id": 56043,
                "src": "pic link",
                "name": "A name",
            }
        ],
    },
]
```

Comment: Please post the full error message including stacktrace. It should point out where the problem is in your code. Also, it would be great if you posted an example of the JSON you are trying to parse since the error indicates a mismatch of types between the JSON and the model.

Comment: are you getting a list after decoding json in bodybytedecoded varieble?

Comment: @Diwyansh yes i do, and also the images is a list.

Comment: Does your response return a list or object?

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your ProductModel

```
List<ProductModel> productFromJson(String str) => List<ProductModel>.from(jsonDecode(str).map((x) => ProductModel.fromJson(x)));
```

and change your code to like this

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      setState(() {
        var bodybytedecoded= jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

  final product= productFromJson(bodybytedecoded); // console shows error come from this line
        print(product);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to Map a List to a Map change this line to

```
 final product= ProductModel.fromJson(bodybytedecoded);
```

to

```
var bodybytedecoded= jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
final List<ProductModel> products = bodybytedecoded
          .map((model) => ProductModel.fromJson(model));
```

On a side note there is a typo in `toJson`

```
 data["regular_rice"] = this.regular_price;
```

Comment: console shows this error: `Unhandled Exception: type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ProductModel>'`

Comment: @NavidShokoufeh please update the main post with http request method. I believe utf8.decode is not required only `jsonDecode(response.body)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by decoding your data and storing the value in the list.

```
 var decodedResponse= jsonDecode(resonse.body); 

List<ProductModel> items=[];
  decodedResponse.forEach((e){
    items.add(ProductModel.fromJson(e));
  });
```

Comment: and follow the link https://gist.github.com/Jahidul007/98e5ea1107fb9dca0bb7809f558776d4